# Finding Length of Semi-Major Axis and Length of Semi-Minor Axis of an ellipse. Given Gradient and intersection of a tangent line.

Tags: conic-sections

**Figure**
[image: Diagram]

I would like to know how to find $a$ and $b$ of an ellipse if I know $K$, $L$ and $m$ as shown in the figure .

I can find the answer to this using the equations below and an `Excel Goal Seek` or `Python` but I'd be interested to see how to solve this directly. I get stuck trying to simplify the simultaneous equations.

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\\
\\
\frac{L^2}{a^2}+\frac{(-b+K)^2}{b^2}=1\quad(1)\\
\\ \\ \\
y= mx\pm \sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}\\
\\
-b+K=mL\pm\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}\;\;\;\;(2)\\
$$

Rearranging $(1)$
$$
a=\sqrt{\frac{L^2}{1-\frac{(-b+K)^2}{b^2}}} 
$$

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There seems to be some inaccuracies with the figure. If $b$ and $K$ are both positive constants, then the y coordinate of the intersection should be $K-b$. I believe that’s what you meant as that’s also what you used in your calculations.

Comment: Yes @person my figure is wrong, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let a tangency point be $P=(x_0,y_0)$ and suppose the normal at $P$ intersects $x$-axis at $K=(d,0)$ (if $m$ is the slope of the tangent, then $d=my_0+x_0$). Foci $F$ and $F'$ lie on $x$-axis at a distance $c$ from the origin and normal $PK$ is the bisector of $\angle FPF'$. Hence:
$$
FK:F'K=FP:F'P,
$$
that is:
$$
(c-d):(c+d)=\sqrt{(c-x_0)^2+y_0^2}:\sqrt{(c+x_0)^2+y_0^2}.
$$
Squaring both sides and simplifying, we can find $c$:
$$
c^2={d(x_0^2+y_0^2-dx_0)\over x_0-d}.
$$
Finally, once we know $c$ we can compute semi-axes: $2a=PF+PF'$ and $b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$.

[image]